# how to add a system command result in jtable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I tried too many ways but i failed to make it 
I will run a system command and i will take the result in a bufferedreader and reading each line and put it in a vector and put it in a row and clear the vector to reuse it but it doesn't work I don't know why please help

this is my code but it crashed and I don't know why

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {     
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
        Vector<Object> row = new Vector();
        running_process ob = new running_process();
        BufferedReader stdInput ; 
        String s;
        stdInput= ob.all_running_ps();
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            row.add(s);
            model.addRow(row);
            row.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and put it in a vector and put it in a row and clear the vector to reuse it but it doesn't work I don't know why

You can't clear the Vector. You need to create a new Vector for every row of data you want to add to the table:

```
while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
    Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>();
    row.add(s);
    model.addRow(row);
}
```

> running_process ob = new running_process();

Also, I don't think you should be running an external process from the listener. This process might block and prevent the EDT from responding to events. You should probably move the code to a `SwingWorker` and "publish" the data to the table as it becomes available.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information about the `EDT` and working code for a `SwingWorker` example.

Comment: thanks a lot it works when i create a new vector every row :)